# Tracking a runtime created, Firebase Dynamic Link, with a dynamic parameter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

I'm using Firebase Dynamic Links to share an item with a unique id. The problem is that this is a link created in runtime and can't be track in the Firebase dashboard.

The question is, can i add it to dashboard or create a new one in the dashboard and attach a param to it on runtime?

(Im using Firebase Invites for sharing it. Don't think it affects the dynamic link somehow though.)

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to track link created in runtime?

Comment: No, i didn't find how to do this :(